# Composer require maatwebsite/excel not installing

Tags: laravel-7, maatwebsite-excel

I am using laravel 7 and php 7.4.3

While using the composer command to install maatwebsite.

It through error u can see in the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6SmB.png) image

Answer (score 1):

You need php extension ext-gd.
If you using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/image.installation.php